# Selectively inserting into a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert into a mysql table. However, It should insert only if a conditions is satisfied. So I want something like this to happen

```
 INSERT INTO table_name(name,qty,code) VALUES(SELECT i.name,i.qty,i.code FROM table2 i);
```

For a condition like this

```
 IF i.code == 'abcd' && i.name == 'def' THEN perform insert ELSE don't insert
```

I can't use a WHERE clause because I want to select and insert all codes except the case when it equals 'abcd', in which case I want to insert based on the condition.

Comment: Use "WHERE (x=m AND y=z) OR (x<>m)"

Comment: Thanks strawberry, seems like the most sane way to do it.

Comment: You should make this an answer @Strawberry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@strawberry answered this question in the comments. It's a simple answer but somehow really nice. Here is the answer

```
 INSERT INTO table_name(name,qty,code) VALUES 
 ( 
    SELECT i.name,i.qty,i.code FROM table2 i
    WHERE (i.code = 'abcd' AND i.name = 'def') OR i.code != 'abcd'
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

first insert all the rows from table2 for code = 'abcd' and name = 'def'

```
INSERT INTO table_name SELECT i.name,i.qty,i.code FROM table2 i where i.code = 'abcd' and i.name = 'def'
```

Now insert conditionally other rows

Comment: It works. But Not as a single transaction. I have provided the answer in the thread below.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
IF (i.code == 'abcd' && i.name == 'def')
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO table_name(name,qty,code) VALUES(SELECT i.name,i.qty,i.code FROM table2 i)
    END 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
         PRINT('DONT DO ANYTHING')
    END
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
INSERT INTO table_name
(name,qty,code) 
VALUES(SELECT i.name,i.qty,i.code FROM table2 i)
WHERE IF(i.code == 'abcd' && i.name == 'def', TRUE, FALSE)
```

Using the MySQL [IF()-Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)